# About image paths in Sass

Tags: css, sass, frontend

My project structure consists of a dist folder which will include all the folders I will deploy (`html`, `css`, `js`), while outside the dist folder will contain my Sass folder. I set my Sass to output the css file into the dist folder.

The problem now is that I currently have a variable that stores an image path. Since the image path needs to be relative to the css file but not the sass file, the image path I've put inside the sass file is `not found`, and therefore adds a red line underneath. Is there a way to solve this issue?

Answer (score 0):

you can try to use full path in the SCSS file , in this way both the SCSS and the compiled CSS will find the image path

Comment: How do I do that? I tried typing "/dist/img/background.jpg" but it didn't work

Comment: For full path you can open the file in file explorer and copy the full path from there, some thing like - d:/documents/myProgramingLibrary/dist//img/background.jpg

Comment: Nope it's still not working after I added a full path